# Multiple CSS Transitions on an Image Gallery

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to combine the following two concepts; however, I am unsure on how to proceed. The first is an image gallery which performs a scale transition on each image. I would like to have a hidden text element which is revealed on hover (after the scale).

So in summary each image element has two parts (image and text). Without a the mouse hover only the image is shown. On hover, the image is scaled and the text is revealed. How would I go about combining? I would prefer this is done completely within CSS3 or SCSS.

Image Gallery with hover transitions:

```css
.div-table {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 400px;
}

.div-table img { width: 100%; }

.div-table div {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  height: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 1s transform;
}

.div-table div:hover {
  z-index: 2;
  transform: scale(2, 2);

}


.div-table div:nth-child(1) { transform-origin : 0 0; }
.div-table div:nth-child(2) { transform-origin : 33.3% 0; }
.div-table div:nth-child(3) { transform-origin : 66.6% 0; }
.div-table div:nth-child(4) { transform-origin : 100% 0; }
.div-table div:nth-child(5) { transform-origin : 0     33.3%; }
.div-table div:nth-child(6) { transform-origin : 33.3% 33.3%; }
.div-table div:nth-child(7) { transform-origin : 66.6% 33.3%; }
.div-table div:nth-child(8) { transform-origin : 100%  33.3%; }
```

```html
<div class="div-table">
    <div><img src="https://placeimg.com/400/400/nature" /></div>
    <div><img src="https://placeimg.com/400/400/people" /></div>
    <div><img src="https://placeimg.com/400/400/architecture" /></div>
    <div><img src="https://placeimg.com/400/400/animals" /></div>
    <div><img src="https://placeimg.com/400/400/animals" /></div>
    <div><img src="https://placeimg.com/400/400/sepia" /></div>
    <div><img src="https://placeimg.com/400/400/grayscale" /></div>
    <div><img src="https://placeimg.com/400/400/tech" /></div>
</div>
```

Text element:

```css
body {margin:0;}

main {overflow:hidden;}

article{float:left; width:20%; transition:width 2s; min-height:10em; 
padding:1em; box-sizing:border-box;} 
aside {float: left; width:0%; transition:width 2s; min-height:10em; 
   padding:0em; box-sizing:border-box;}
article {clear: left; background:#ffc;}
aside {background:#cff; text-indent:-9999px}

article:hover {height: 10em; width:18%; !important;}
article:hover ~ aside {height: 10em; width:15%; text-indent:10px}
```

```html
<main>
 <article>
<h1>Main content</h1>
 </article>
 <aside>
  Crouching Tiger, Hidden Text
 </aside>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

The key to getting one transition to play after the other is to use `transition-delay`. By setting the delay to `1s` the transition that reveals the text is actioned once the image transition has occurred.

The text is positioned absolutely (relatively to the containing `div`) to avoid it effecting the flexbox layout of `.div-table`, this is because absolutely positioned elements are taken out of the document flow so won't change the width of the containing element. `left: 100%;` is used to make the text appear to the right of the image.

```css
.div-table {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 400px;
}

.div-table img {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.div-table span {
  background: #cff;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  left: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  transition: width 2s;
  transition-delay: 1s;
  width: 0%;
}

.div-table div {
  cursor: pointer;
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  transition: 1s transform;
}

.div-table div:hover {
  transform: scale(2, 2);
  z-index: 2;
}

.div-table div:hover span {
  width: 100%;
}

.div-table div:nth-child(1) {
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.div-table div:nth-child(2) {
  transform-origin: 33.3% 0;
}

.div-table div:nth-child(3) {
  transform-origin: 66.6% 0;
}

.div-table div:nth-child(4) {
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
}

.div-table div:nth-child(5) {
  transform-origin: 0 33.3%;
}

.div-table div:nth-child(6) {
  transform-origin: 33.3% 33.3%;
}

.div-table div:nth-child(7) {
  transform-origin: 66.6% 33.3%;
}

.div-table div:nth-child(8) {
  transform-origin: 100% 33.3%;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-table">
  <div>
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/400/nature" />
    <span>Crouching Tiger, Hidden Text</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/400/people" />
    <span>Crouching Tiger, Hidden Text</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/400/architecture" />
    <span>Crouching Tiger, Hidden Text</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/400/animals" />
    <span>Crouching Tiger, Hidden Text</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/400/animals" />
    <span>Crouching Tiger, Hidden Text</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/400/sepia" />
    <span>Crouching Tiger, Hidden Text</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/400/grayscale" />
    <span>Crouching Tiger, Hidden Text</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/400/tech" />
    <span>Crouching Tiger, Hidden Text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```